# Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: html, angular

I want to do validation and save email value to db. But it shows the "Cannot assign to a reference or variable"

***HTML File***

```
<div  class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <span><input id="email" [required]="!standingQueue" type="text" class="form-control" name="email"
            [(ngModel)]="email" #email></span>
          </div>
```

Comment: You can not have #email and [(ngModel)]="email" with same name. "#email " is for element reference

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `ngModel` and the template variable to be the same text. This should work

```
<input id="email" [required]="!standingQueue" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="emailEntry" #email>
```

Now you can bind to the `emailEntry` variable.